# Eroro: Call to a member function validatePassword() on a non-object

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to install Humbhub, and I'm pretty much new to Yii framework, and I've got the error below on my login page;

> Error: Call to a member function validatePassword() on a non-object

Here is my accountlogin.php source code;

```
<?php

namespace humhub\modules\user\models\forms;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use humhub\modules\user\models\User;
use humhub\modules\user\libs\Ldap;
use humhub\models\Setting;
use yii\db\Expression;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
*/
class AccountLogin extends Model
{

/**
 * @var string user's username or email address
 */
public $username;
public $password;
public $rememberMe = true;
private $_user = false;

/**
 * @return array the validation rules.
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
        ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
        ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ['username', 'validateUser'],
    ];
}

/**
 * Validates the password.
 * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
 *
 * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
 * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
 */
public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
{
    if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
         $user = $user = $this->getUser(); 
        if ($user !== null) {
            if ($user->auth_mode === User::AUTH_MODE_LOCAL && $user->currentPassword->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                return;
            } elseif ($user->auth_mode === User::AUTH_MODE_LDAP && Ldap::isAvailable() && Ldap::getInstance()->authenticate($user->username, $this->$password)) {
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
    }
}

public function validateUser($attribute, $params)
{
    if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if ($user !== null) {
            if ($user->status == User::STATUS_DISABLED) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Your account is disabled!');
            }
            if ($user->status == User::STATUS_NEED_APPROVAL) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Your account is not approved yet!');
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
 * @return boolean whether the user is logged in successfully
 */
public function login()
{
    if ($this->validate() && Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0)) {
        $this->_user->last_login = new Expression('NOW()');
        $this->_user->save();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Finds user by [[username]]
 *
 * @return User|null
 */
public function getUser()
{
    if ($this->_user === false) {
        $this->_user = User::find()->where(['username' => $this->username])->orWhere(['email' => $this->username])->one();

        // Could not found user -> lookup in LDAP
        if ($this->_user === null && Ldap::isAvailable() && Setting::Get('enabled', 'authentication_ldap')) {

            // Try load/create LDAP user
            $usernameDn = Ldap::getInstance()->ldap->getCanonicalAccountName($this->username, \Zend\Ldap\Ldap::ACCTNAME_FORM_DN);
            Ldap::getInstance()->handleLdapUser(Ldap::getInstance()->ldap->getNode($usernameDn));

            // Check if user is availble now
            $this->_user = User::find()->where(['username' => $this->username])->orWhere(['email' => $this->username])->one();
        }
    }

    return $this->_user;
  }

}
```

I've tried changing `$user = $this->getUser();`to `$user = new User();` and the error were gone, but then my login credentials were not properly validated and I get the error `wrong username or email`on the login form, 
What is the possible solution? any material to study ? any consideration is highly appreciated...

**Update:**
   User model source code:

```
<?php

 /**
 * @link https://www.humhub.org/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2015 HumHub GmbH & Co. KG
 * @license https://www.humhub.com/licences
 */

 namespace humhub\modules\user\models;

 use Yii;
 use yii\base\Exception;
 use humhub\modules\content\components\ContentContainerActiveRecord;
 use humhub\modules\user\models\GroupAdmin;
 use humhub\modules\user\components\ActiveQueryUser;

 /**
  * This is the model class for table "user".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $guid
 * @property integer $wall_id
 * @property integer $group_id
 * @property integer $status
 * @property integer $super_admin
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $auth_mode
 * @property string $tags
 * @property string $language
 * @property string $time_zone
 * @property string $last_activity_email
 * @property string $created_at
 * @property integer $created_by
 * @property string $updated_at
 * @property integer $updated_by
 * @property string $last_login
 * @property integer $visibility
 */
 class User extends ContentContainerActiveRecord implements \yii\web   \IdentityInterface, \humhub\modules\search\interfaces\Searchable
 {

 /**
  * Authentication Modes
 */
 const AUTH_MODE_LDAP = "ldap";
 const AUTH_MODE_LOCAL = "local";

 /**
 * User Status Flags
 */
 const STATUS_DISABLED = 0;
 const STATUS_ENABLED = 1;
 const STATUS_NEED_APPROVAL = 2;

 /**
 * E-Mail Settings (Value Stored in UserSetting)
 */
 const RECEIVE_EMAIL_NEVER = 0;
 const RECEIVE_EMAIL_DAILY_SUMMARY = 1;
 const RECEIVE_EMAIL_WHEN_OFFLINE = 2;
 const RECEIVE_EMAIL_ALWAYS = 3;

 /**
 * Visibility Modes
 */
 const VISIBILITY_REGISTERED_ONLY = 1; // Only for registered members
 const VISIBILITY_ALL = 2; // Visible for all (also guests)

 /**
 * @inheritdoc
 */

 public static function tableName()
 {
    return 'user';
 }

 /**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
 public function rules()
 {
    return [
        [['username', 'email'], 'required'],
        [['wall_id', 'group_id', 'status', 'super_admin', 'created_by', 'updated_by', 'visibility'], 'integer'],
        [['tags'], 'string'],
        [['last_activity_email', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'last_login'], 'safe'],
        [['guid'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
        [['username'], 'string', 'max' => 25, 'min' => Yii::$app->params['user']['minUsernameLength']],
        [['time_zone'], 'in', 'range' => \DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()],
        [['email'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['auth_mode'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
        [['language'], 'string', 'max' => 5],
        [['email'], 'unique'],
        [['username'], 'unique'],
        [['guid'], 'unique'],
        [['wall_id'], 'unique']
    ];
}

public function __get($name)
{
    /**
     * Ensure there is always a related Profile Model also when it's
     * not really exists yet.
     */
    if ($name == 'profile') {
        $profile = parent::__get('profile');
        if (!$this->isRelationPopulated('profile') || $profile === null) {
            $profile = new Profile();
            $profile->user_id = $this->id;
            $this->populateRelation('profile', $profile);
        }
        return $profile;
    }
    return parent::__get($name);
}

public function scenarios()
{
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
    $scenarios['login'] = ['username', 'password'];
    $scenarios['editAdmin'] = ['username', 'email', 'group_id', 'super_admin', 'auth_mode', 'status'];
    $scenarios['registration'] = ['username', 'email', 'group_id'];
    return $scenarios;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'guid' => 'Guid',
        'wall_id' => 'Wall ID',
        'group_id' => 'Group ID',
        'status' => 'Status',
        'super_admin' => 'Super Admin',
        'username' => 'Username',
        'email' => 'Email',
        'auth_mode' => 'Auth Mode',
        'tags' => 'Tags',
        'language' => 'Language',
        'last_activity_email' => 'Last Activity Email',
        'created_at' => 'Created At',
        'created_by' => 'Created By',
        'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
        'updated_by' => 'Updated By',
        'last_login' => 'Last Login',
        'visibility' => 'Visibility',
    ];
}

public function behaviors()
{
    return array(
        \humhub\components\behaviors\GUID::className(),
        \humhub\modules\user\behaviors\UserSetting::className(),
        \humhub\modules\user\behaviors\Followable::className(),
        \humhub\modules\user\behaviors\UserModelModules::className()
    );
}

public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    return static::findOne($id);
}

public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
{
    return static::findOne(['guid' => $token]);
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 * 
 * @return ActiveQueryContent
 */
public static function find()
{
    return Yii::createObject(ActiveQueryUser::className(), [get_called_class()]);
}

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getAuthKey()
{
    return $this->guid;
}

public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
{
    return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
}

public function getCurrentPassword()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Password::className(), ['user_id' => 'id'])->orderBy('created_at DESC');
}

public function getProfile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getGroup()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Group::className(), ['id' => 'group_id']);
}

/**
 * Before Delete of a User
 *
 */
public function beforeDelete()
{

    // We don't allow deletion of users who owns a space - validate that
    foreach (\humhub\modules\space\models\Membership::GetUserSpaces($this->id) as $space) {
        if ($space->isSpaceOwner($this->id)) {
            throw new Exception("Tried to delete a user which is owner of a space!");
        }
    }

    // Disable all enabled modules
    foreach ($this->getAvailableModules() as $moduleId => $module) {
        if ($this->isModuleEnabled($moduleId)) {
            $this->disableModule($moduleId);
        }
    }

    // Delete profile image
    $this->getProfileImage()->delete();

    // Remove from search index
    Yii::$app->search->delete($this);

    // Cleanup related tables
    Invite::deleteAll(['user_originator_id' => $this->id]);
    Follow::deleteAll(['user_id' => $this->id]);
    Follow::deleteAll(['object_model' => $this->className(), 'object_id' => $this->id]);
    Password::deleteAll(['user_id' => $this->id]);
    Profile::deleteAll(['user_id' => $this->id]);
    GroupAdmin::deleteAll(['user_id' => $this->id]);
    Session::deleteAll(['user_id' => $this->id]);
    Setting::deleteAll(['user_id' => $this->id]);

    return parent::beforeDelete();
}

/**
 * Before Save Addons
 *
 * @return type
 */
public function beforeSave($insert)
{

    if ($insert) {

        if ($this->auth_mode == "") {
            $this->auth_mode = self::AUTH_MODE_LOCAL;
        }

        if (\humhub\models\Setting::Get('allowGuestAccess', 'authentication_internal')) {
            // Set users profile default visibility to all
            if (\humhub\models\Setting::Get('defaultUserProfileVisibility', 'authentication_internal') == User::VISIBILITY_ALL) {
                $this->visibility = User::VISIBILITY_ALL;
            }
        }

        $this->last_activity_email = new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()');

        // Set Status
        if ($this->status == "") {
            if (\humhub\models\Setting::Get('needApproval', 'authentication_internal')) {
                $this->status = User::STATUS_NEED_APPROVAL;
            } else {
                $this->status = User::STATUS_ENABLED;
            }
        }

        if ((\humhub\models\Setting::Get('defaultUserGroup', 'authentication_internal'))) {
            $this->group_id = \humhub\models\Setting::Get('defaultUserGroup', 'authentication_internal');
        }
    }

    if ($this->time_zone == "") {
        $this->time_zone = \humhub\models\Setting::Get('timeZone');
    }

    if ($this->group_id == "") {
        throw new \yii\base\Exception("Could not save user without group!");
    }

    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}

/**
 * After Save Addons
 *
 * @return type
 */
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
    if ($this->status == User::STATUS_ENABLED) {
        Yii::$app->search->update($this);
    } else {
        Yii::$app->search->delete($this);
    }
    if ($insert) {
        if ($this->status == User::STATUS_ENABLED) {
            $this->setUpApproved();
        } else {
            $this->group->notifyAdminsForUserApproval($this);
        }
        $this->profile->user_id = $this->id;
    }

    if (Yii::$app->user->id == $this->id) {
        Yii::$app->user->setIdentity($this);
    }
    return parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
}

public function setUpApproved()
{
    $userInvite = Invite::findOne(['email' => $this->email]);

    if ($userInvite !== null) {
        // User was invited to a space
        if ($userInvite->source == Invite::SOURCE_INVITE) {
            $space = \humhub\modules\space\models\Space::findOne(['id' => $userInvite->space_invite_id]);
            if ($space != null) {
                $space->addMember($this->id);
            }
        }

        // Delete/Cleanup Invite Entry
        $userInvite->delete();
    }

    // Auto Assign User to the Group Space
    $group = Group::findOne(['id' => $this->group_id]);
    if ($group != null && $group->space_id != "") {
        $space = \humhub\modules\space\models\Space::findOne(['id' => $group->space_id]);
        if ($space !== null) {
            $space->addMember($this->id);
        }
    }

    // Auto Add User to the default spaces
    foreach (\humhub\modules\space\models\Space::findAll(['auto_add_new_members' => 1]) as $space) {
        $space->addMember($this->id);
    }

    // Create new wall record for this user
    $wall = new \humhub\modules\content\models\Wall;
    $wall->object_model = $this->className();
    $wall->object_id = $this->id;
    $wall->save();

    $this->wall_id = $wall->id;

    $this->update(false, ['wall_id']);
}

/**
 * Returns users display name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDisplayName()
{

    $name = '';

    $format = \humhub\models\Setting::Get('displayNameFormat');

    if ($this->profile !== null && $format == '{profile.firstname} {profile.lastname}')
        $name = $this->profile->firstname . " " . $this->profile->lastname;

    // Return always username as fallback
    if ($name == '' || $name == ' ')
        return $this->username;

    return $name;
}

/**
 * Checks if this records belongs to the current user
 *
 * @return boolean is current User
 */
public function isCurrentUser()
{
    if (Yii::$app->user->id == $this->id) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public function canAccessPrivateContent(User $user = null)
{
    return ($this->isCurrentUser());
}

public function getWallOut()
{
    return \humhub\modules\user\widgets\UserWall::widget(['user' => $this]);
}

/**
 * Returns an array with assigned Tags
 */
public function getTags()
{

    // split tags string into individual tags
    return preg_split("/[;,#]+/", $this->tags);
}

/**
 * Checks if given userId can write to this users wall
 *
 * @param type $userId
 * @return type
 */
public function canWrite($userId = "")
{

    if ($userId == "")
        $userId = Yii::$app->user->id;

    if ($userId == $this->id)
        return true;

    return false;
}

/**
 * Returns an array of informations used by search subsystem.
 * Function is defined in interface ISearchable
 *
 * @return Array
 */
public function getSearchAttributes()
{
    $attributes = array(
        'email' => $this->email,
        'username' => $this->username,
        'tags' => $this->tags,
        'firstname' => $this->profile->firstname,
        'lastname' => $this->profile->lastname,
        'title' => $this->profile->title,
    );

    if (!$this->profile->isNewRecord) {
        foreach ($this->profile->getProfileFields() as $profileField) {
            $attributes['profile_' . $profileField->internal_name] = $profileField->getUserValue($this, true);
        }
    }

    return $attributes;
}

public function createUrl($route = null, $params = array(), $scheme = false)
{
    if ($route === null) {
        $route = '/user/profile';
    }

    array_unshift($params, $route);
    if (!isset($params['uguid'])) {
        $params['uguid'] = $this->guid;
    }

    return \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute($params, $scheme);
}

/**
 *
 * @return type
 */
public function getSpaces()
{

    // TODO: SHOW ONLY REAL MEMBERSHIPS
    return $this->hasMany(\humhub\modules\space\models\Space::className(), ['id' => 'space_id'])
                    ->viaTable('space_membership', ['user_id' => 'id']);
}

/**
 * @return type
 */
public function getHttpSessions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\humhub\modules\user\models\Session::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}

/**
 * Checks if the user can create a space
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function canCreateSpace()
{
    return ($this->canCreatePrivateSpace() || $this->canCreatePublicSpace());
}

/**
 * User can approve other users
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function canApproveUsers()
{
    if ($this->super_admin == 1) {
        return true;
    }

    if (GroupAdmin::find()->where(['user_id' => $this->id])->count() != 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Checks if the user can create public spaces
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function canCreatePublicSpace()
{
    if ($this->super_admin) {
        return true;
    } elseif ($this->group !== null && $this->group->can_create_public_spaces == 1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Checks if user can create private spaces
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function canCreatePrivateSpace()
{

    if ($this->super_admin) {
        return true;
    } elseif ($this->group !== null && $this->group->can_create_private_spaces == 1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

 }
```

**Update:** config.php in user's module

```
<?php

use humhub\modules\search\engine\Search;
use humhub\modules\user\Events;
use humhub\commands\IntegrityController;
use humhub\modules\content\components\ContentAddonActiveRecord;
use humhub\modules\content\components\ContentActiveRecord;
use humhub\commands\CronController;

return [
'id' => 'user',
'class' => \humhub\modules\user\Module::className(),
'isCoreModule' => true,
'urlManagerRules' => [
    ['class' => 'humhub\modules\user\components\UrlRule']
],
'events' => [
    ['class' => Search::className(), 'event' => Search::EVENT_ON_REBUILD, 'callback' => array(Events::className(), 'onSearchRebuild')],
    ['class' => ContentActiveRecord::className(), 'event' => ContentActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_DELETE, 'callback' => array(Events::className(), 'onContentDelete')],
    ['class' => ContentAddonActiveRecord::className(), 'event' => ContentAddonActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_DELETE, 'callback' => array(Events::className(), 'onContentDelete')],
    ['class' => IntegrityController::className(), 'event' => IntegrityController::EVENT_ON_RUN, 'callback' => array(Events::className(), 'onIntegrityCheck')],
    ['class' => CronController::className(), 'event' => CronController::EVENT_ON_HOURLY_RUN, 'callback' => [Events::className(), 'onHourlyCron']],
]
];
?>
```

Comment: Do you use basic or advanced template?

Comment: Please post your config /main.php  modules user content

Comment: Just to mention, the server I've done the humbhub installation on has diasbled 'ini_set', and I've had to go ahead and comment it out in several places, I haven't properly considered if it affects the other components, do you think it does ?

Comment: The error you showed is related to the fact the object doesn't not exist and then you try to use a function for a non object.. I would check what user class you are using.. and then check how you create and call the object..  A first look the ini_set question seems not related but .. for the moment i don't know..

Comment: so, any idea so far ?

Comment: show me the  config /main.php modules user content and the contrioller action where do you call the login..

Comment: are you it's named main.php ? I ain't got no main.php in configure, it's only common.php....

Comment: You are use the action in frontEnd or in backend?..anyway show also common.php modules user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99304/discussion-between-neophyte-polyhistor-and-scaisedge).